# HBase REST API batch attribute not working

Tags: rest, hbase, cloudera

When trying to scan HBase through the REST API in our cluster (CDH 5.14.0 | HBase 1.2.0-cdh5.14.0) the scanner's `batch` attribute is not working, always returns records one by one. The PUT request is as follows:

```
http://hbase-rest-server:20550/our-table/scanner/
```

With a scanner definition like:

```
<Scanner batch="1000" startRow="YWFh" stopRow="YmJi=" />
```

With the scanner `id` that comes in the response's location returns one record in every call in order:

```
http://hbase-rest-server:20550/our-table/scanner/1532043234571885278a
```

Why `batch="1000"` is not taken into account? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In application/octet-stream option, the scaner will ignore batching parameter.
Set Accept header to text/xml or any other options.

https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html